# jquery $(document).one ('ready', function () {...} does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using `$(document).ready(function(){...});` (version 1), the document ready function fires indefinitely. My guess is that the ready is fired everytime the jquery .load function finishes? Would like to confirm.

So I tried using jquery's `$(document).one('ready', function(){...});` function (version 2), but the function doesn't fire at all. What is wrong here?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="index__header"></div>
    <div class="index__content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js version 1:

```
var _index = {
    loadLogin : function () {
        $(".index__content").load("/view/login.html");
    }
};

$(document).ready ( function () {
    $(".index__header").load("/view/header.html");
    _index.loadLogin();
});
```

index.js version 2:

```
var _index = {
    loadLogin : function () {
        $(".index__content").load("/view/login.html");
    }
};

$(document).one ('ready', function () {
    console.log('ready...');
    $(".index__header").load("/view/header.html");
    _index.loadLogin();
});
```

Comment: what error you are getting on console ?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Load the login after header? Then do `$(function() {  $(".index__content").load("/view/header.html",function() {
$(".index__content").load("/view/login.html");  });});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` is implemented in a special way. When it's used before the document is ready, it establishes a listener for the `DOMReady` event. But if it's called again after the document is ready, it simply executes the code unconditionally, it doesn't wait for an event (because the `DOMReady` event only occurs once).

`ready` isn't a real event, so `.one()` won't work with it.

Comment: Well, `.on('ready')` and `.one('ready')` do actually work in jQuery 1.x and 2.x, though it is removed in 3.x.  So, the event is simulated in some versions.  See https://jsfiddle.net/z9vhLaLn/.  The jQuery `.ready()` doc page discusses this.

Comment: The `$(document).on('ready', handler)` is removed from jQuery 3.x (see [jQuery api docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))

Answer (score 5):

There is no point to doing `$(document).one ('ready',...)` and that form is also deprecated.  The ready handler is only ever fired once anyway.  Certainly if you reload your entire page, that creates a new document which will be loaded again.  But operations within a given document, do not trigger `.ready()` again.

In addition, I believe I read somewhere that it is deprecated to use `$(document).on('ready', ...)` and that the proper forms are:

```
$(document).ready(...)
$(function() {...})
```

Ahh, yes here's the [note about the "ready" event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) using `.on()` being deprecated:

> There is also `$(document).on("ready", handler)`, deprecated as of
>   jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0.

---

If you really think that a ready handler is getting called multiple times, you need to show us exactly how that is happening because that is not supposed to be the case.  In fact, inside the `.ready()` implementation a registered callback is permanently removed from the list as soon as it is called (thus forgetting about it forever) so it's hard to imagine how it could ever get called again (unless you double registered the same callback).

Keep in mind that if you use `.ready()` after the document is already ready, it will just call the callback you supply right away.  That's how the `.ready()` functionality is defined.  So, if you're regularly reregistering `.ready()` handlers, they will keep getting called each time you register them (after the document is ready).

---

FYI, if what you're trying to do is to figure out when newly loaded content is ready for us, then you should be using the callback that can be provided to `.load()`:

```
$(".index__header").load("/view/header.html", function() {
    // newly loaded content is ready now
});
```